# Angular-AppComponent error. How solve it?

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I have a problem with my Angular project. In my app.module.ts the code is below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BmiModule } from './bmi/bmi.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BmiModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app.component.ts is below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'WP4_HF_004';
}
```

My app.component.html:

```
<h1>BMI kalkulátor</h1>
<p>Ez egy BMI kalkulátor. A lenti 4 gomb segítségével lehet módosítani a súly- és magasságparamétereket.
    <app-bmi-calculator></app-bmi-calculator>
</p>
```

I got an error in app.module.ts:

> Component AppComponent is standalone, and cannot be declared in an NgModule. Did you mean to import it instead?

If I didn't import my AppComponent in `app.module.ts` I get an error in app.component.html:

> 'app-bmi-calculator' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-bmi-calculator' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
> 2. If 'app-bmi-calculator' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)
>    app.component.ts(4, 5):

Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

I searched the problem on the internet but I didn't find the solve.

Comment: Standalone app component must be bootstrapped in a different way.

Check this out :) https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

Answer (score -1):

Standalone app component must be bootstrapped in a different way.

Check this out :) https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch((err) =>
  console.error(err)
);
```

**app/app.config.ts**

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(appRoutes) /* ... other providers */],
};
```

**app/app.routes**

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';

export const appRoutes: Route[] = [/* route declarations */];
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35518875)

Comment: thank you @wohlstad. It sounds reasonable. Let me add some code to that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I got to your answer via the review queues. It was detected as a potential low-quality one due to the reasons mentioned above. BTW - I am not actually familiar with this subject, so I cannot evaluate the quality of your answer.

Comment: @wohlstad Sure thing, I totally understand. Someone voted against, but honestly, I don't know why :)

Answer (score -1):

In fact you can use just the standalone components with no modules, but you can try this:

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BmiModule } from './bmi/bmi.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BmiModule,],
  template: `
    <h1>BMI kalkulátor</h1>
    <p>Ez egy BMI kalkulátor. A lenti 4 gomb segítségével lehet módosítani a súly- és magasságparamétereket.
    <app-bmi-calculator></app-bmi-calculator>
</p>
  `,
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'WP4_HF_004';
}
```

I have no idea what's in the BmiModule, i hope it will not cause any issue.

**Edit**: you can try just to delete this line `standalone: true,` since you imported in the declaration array.